# How to call std::min() when min has been defined as a macro?

Tags: c++, stl, macros

How do I call `std::min` when `min` has already been defined as a macro?

Comment: mercilessly `#undef min` and go with standard facilities.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
(std::min)(x,y)
```

The parentheses around `min` prevent macro expansion. This works with all function macros.

Comment: @André: Yes. Calling a function like this is given as an example in `[n3290: 3.4.2]`, and it's clear that this would prevent macro expansion (`6.10.3/10` in C99; I'm sure the wording is nearby in C90.)

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity, is there a way to prevent the expansion of a simple `#define foo 5` macro, or is this override behavior only for functions?

Answer (score 22):

On Windows, you need to define `NOMINMAX` before including any windows headers, preferable at the beginning of precompiled header.

Comment: Cool! Not portable, but I still like it; +1. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: including Windows headers is already non-portable as it stands.

Comment: @Andre: I agree, that's precisely why I said I still like it.. :P

Comment: Can also use /D NOMINMAX command-line option in the project file. This is a useful alternative if you don't have PCH's.

Answer (score 6):

Use `#undef min` in your code, after `#include <>` directives.

```
#include <...> // bad header that defines `min` macro
#ifdef min
#undef min
#endif

// rest f code.
```

**Addendum**: If you need to keep the value of the `min` macro afterwards, you can disable its definition temporarily using a non-portable solution on some compilers.  For instance, Microsoft's C++ compiler has a [`push_macro` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bs04eza.aspx) that also seems to be [supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html).

Comment: Er, I can't really do that because that messes up everything afterward that could depend on the macro for some reason... it's a rather poor hack, not a real solution. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: `min` as a macro is a hack to begin with. Best to avoid it. If you really want a macro, use one named `MIN` or something else that does not collide.

Comment: @Mehrdad: posted a solution for temporary disabling instead.  However, there's no portable solution as the language clearly states that if a macro is defined, then the textual replacement is done by the pre-processor and appears replaced to the compiler.  There's no C++ language construct that can be used to distinguish `min` the function and `min` the macro.

Comment: @hammar: The trouble is that you're assuming that this is in a C++ file. If this is a header file, it'll screw up whoever includes it, because they don't expect this to happen. (Edit: For the temporary disabling, I guess that works, but I was hoping for a better solution..)

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to avoid the macro definition by:

- `#undef`
- avoid the definition in the first place (either by configuration such as `#define NOMINMAX` or similar or avoiding including the offending header)

If those options can't be used or you don't want to use them, you can always avoid invoking a function-like macro with an appropriate use of parens:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

#define min(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int main() 
{
    printf( "min is %d\n", (std::min)( 3, 5));  // note: the macro version of `min` is avoided
}
```

This is portable and has worked since the dark, early days of C.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of other ways to do it:

Method 1:

```
using std::min;
min(a, b);   // uses either the macro or the function (don't add side effects!)
```

Method 2:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION
#define BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION
#endif

...
std::min BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION(a, b)
```