# g++ expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, g++

I'm getting this error when using `stl_vector.h`. I'm on Linux using g++ to compile.

```
{
  if (max_size() - size() < __n)
    __throw_length_error(__N(__s));

  const size_type __len = size() + std::max(size(), __n); //THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE!
  return (__len < size() || __len > max_size()) ? max_size() : __len;
}
```

> usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:1143:40: error: expected unqualified-id before `‘(’` token

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I have searched a lot and found some "similar" problems but I can't solve mine.

EDIT: so here's the error log:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/vector:65:0,
             from ../../RL_Toolbox/include/caction.h:34,
             from ../../RL_Toolbox/include/cagent.h:35,
             from shortestpathQLearning.cpp:42:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:1143:40: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

You can see in the previous error log that "vector" gets called by the header "caction.h" like this:

```
//THESE ARE THE INCLUDES IN "caction.h"
#ifndef CACTION_H
#define CACTION_H
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <vector> //HERE IT CALLS <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include "cbaseobjects.h"
```

then Vector calls bits/stl_vector.h like this:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_VECTOR
#define _GLIBCXX_VECTOR 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/stl_algobase.h>
#include <bits/allocator.h>
#include <bits/stl_construct.h>
#include <bits/stl_uninitialized.h>
#include <bits/stl_vector.h>//HERE IT CALLS stl_vector.h
#include <bits/stl_bvector.h> //Im actually getting the exact same error from  stl_vector.h on this header
```

just the last 2 headers from vector (stl_vector and stl_bvector) give me the exact same error, the rest are ok. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you happen to have a `#define max` or something like that somewhere?

Comment: Just guessing, but try removing the const.

Comment: Are you including `stl_vector.h` directly or the `vector` header

Comment: Can you look at the file after the pre-processor has done its job. That may reveal the problem.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using `<vector>`? `stl_vector.h` is supposed to be an implementation detail that isn't even guaranteed to be there.

Comment: @Dabbler: This isn't his code. It is in bits/stl_vector.h, the body of `size_type _M_check_len()`.

Comment: What's in the first 41 lines of `shortestpathQLearning.cpp`? Also you could try looking at the output of the pre-processor to see if that helps (`gcc -E`).

Comment: @user786653 the first 41 lines are comments, then just includes and then the main starts

Answer (score 12):

This may be caused by the preprocessor damaging your code, probably because you have macro `max` defined. This can happen with the C library, because generally the C standard allows C standard library functions to be actually macros (although I've only seen such a mishap on MSVC).

To check, you can

- preprocess the source with `gcc -E` and search the output for the corresponding code. Check if it is undamaged.
- add an `#undef max` line before `#include <vector>` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the #undef max fixed the problem : )

Comment: This saved me, I was using someone else's code and had no idea what was going on.

Comment: This solves my problem. Getting same error in linux g++. This was due to the macro "max" is defined in my code. This error disappears, after renaming this macro.

Comment: For those compiling on Windows (or `winegcc`), this may also be resolved by setting `NOMINMAX` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449671/3196753

Answer (score 2):

user977480, given that you said "I'm getting this error when using stl_vector.h", I assume that means your code is using something like `#include <bits/stl_vector.h>` or `#include <c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h>`.

This `#include` statement is the cause of your problem. You need to use `#include <vector>` instead. stl_vector.h is an implementation detail and it does not work by itself. The `vector` header file includes bits/stl_vector.h after it has included some other implementation detail files, including the one that defines `std::max`.

Comment: Hey, i added a little more explanation about this error in the main post, im using #include <vector> but then when vector calls that header <bits/stl_vector.h> thats when i get the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Never use identifiers starting with either a double underscore, or an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, unless they're provided by the implementation.</strike>

<strike>The compiler and/or standard library are permitted to use `__N`, `__s`, `__len`, and so forth, in any way they like.</strike>

<strike>It's not obvious that that's your problem, but see what happens if you change all those identifiers.</strike>

**EDIT**: I was wrong, the code you posted is part of the implementation, so its use of reserved identifiers is perfectly appropriate.

`/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h` on my system contains the same code.  Most likely something in your own code is causing the error.  For example, if I do

```
#include <bits/stl_vector.h>
```

I get 156 errors.  The correct way is

```
#include <vector>
```

but if you `#define` certain macros before the `#include <vector>` it might cause the problem you're seeing.

Show us *your* code, preferably narrowed down to the smallest source file that exhibits the error.

Comment: He's showing code that comes with his compiler's standard library, so he can't change it, nor should he.

Comment: @ildjarn: Quite right, thanks.  I should have noticed that myself.

Comment: @KeithThompson I added a more detailed explanation. THanks a lot for your help